# finding broken rows in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I find a line in notepad++ which has more than 7 numbers?

```
1 1 30 0.111000  -5.13248 -10.7541 12.5497
```

I know that one zero or something else in between these numbers.
I tried marking lines, but I could not find the right command.

Comment: Is this a problem you're looking to solve with code?

Comment: no, just marking the line would be enough from the mark tab of notepad++.

Comment: Then you're asking how you can do this manually?

Comment: yes, I need the right command.

Comment: There is no command. This requires code, in which case to be on-topic here you have to have at lest tried something, or doing it manually, in which case you need to figure out how to use your editor and it's off-topic.

Comment: Find what: ^.{15,}, you see, using this won't help me because it counts characters, but I want to count numbers.

Comment: That's a start. Build on that if you want to use a regular expression and add it to your question with an edit.

Comment: Hint: a line with more than 7 numbers has 8 or more numbers. So look for a line that contains 8 (or more) numbers. Next: what is a number for your purposes? Do some research on regular expressions and you will quickly find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*(?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\h+[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?){7,}\h*$`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  \h*       : 0 or more horizontal spaces
  (?:       : start non capture group
    [+-]?   : optional + or -
    \d+     : 1 or more digit
    (?:     : start non capture group
      \.\d+ : a dot followed by 1 or more digit
    )?      : the group is optional (ie. no decimals)
  )         : end group
  (?:       : start non capture group
    \h+     : 1 or more horizontal spaces
    [+-]?   : optional + or -
    \d+     : 1 or more digit
    (?:     : start non capture group
      \.\d+ : start non capture group
    )?      : the group is optional (ie. no decimals)
  ){7,}     : the group must be present 7 or more times
  \h*       : 0 or more horizontal spaces
$           : end of line
```